# Change non ascii character in an HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, url, faraday

i have to make an http get call to an external service. By sending an address, the latitude and longitude coordinates are returned. The problem is that if the address is Russian or French I have errors like:

```
URI must be ascii only "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?format=json&addressdetails=1&q={Barrage de G\u00E9nissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rh\u00F4ne-Alpes, Francia metropolitana, 74910, Francia}&format=json"
```

My code is:

```
url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?format=json&addressdetails=1&q={"+ address_search +"}&format=json";
response = Faraday.get url
```

the variable address_search is:

```
 Barrage de Génissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Francia metropolitana, 74910, Francia
```

Faraday is just a grm in rails to make an HTTP request, nothing strange. I have to manipulate the URL. Do you have any suggestion?

EDIT:

```
  print Rails.logger.info "body " + response.body
    print Rails.logger.info response.status
    print Rails.logger.info response.env.url
```

This is the output

```
body []
200
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&format=json&q=Barrage+de+G%C3%A9nissiat%2C+Rue+Marcel+Paul%2C+Injoux%2C+Franclens%2C+Nantua%2C+Ain%2C+Auvergne-Rh%C3%B4ne-Alpes%2C+Francia+metropolitana%2C+74910%2C+Francia
  Rendering homes/index.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Answer (score 1):

The query should be encoded, you can do it manually:

```
query = 'Barrage de Génissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Francia metropolitana, 74910, Francia'
address_search = URI.escape(query)
url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?format=json&addressdetails=1&q=#{address_search}&format=json"
response = Faraday.get(url)
```

Or leave the job for Faraday:

```
query = 'Barrage de Génissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Francia metropolitana, 74910, Francia'
connection = Faraday.new('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org')
response = connection.get do |request|
  request.params = { format: 'json', addressdetails: 1, q: query }
end
```

Here is the response:

```
=> #<Faraday::Response:0x0000556afc452060
 @env=
  #<struct Faraday::Env
   method=:get,
   body=
    "[{\"place_id\":104161692,\"licence\":\"Data \xC2\xA9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright\",\"osm_type\":\"way\",\"osm_id\":80667335,\"boundingbox\":[\"46.0516289\",\"46.0531641\",\"5.8112371\",\"5.81
4139\"],\"lat\":\"46.0523765\",\"lon\":\"5.812744291298651\",\"display_name\":\"Barrage de G\xC3\xA9nissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rh\xC3\xB4ne-Alpes, France m\xC3\xA9tropolitaine, 74910, France\"
,\"class\":\"tourism\",\"type\":\"attraction\",\"importance\":1.7983764706069638,\"icon\":\"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/images/mapicons/poi_point_of_interest.p.20.png\",\"address\":{\"tourism\":\"Barrage de G\xC3\xA9nissiat\
",\"road\":\"Rue Marcel Paul\",\"suburb\":\"Injoux\",\"village\":\"Franclens\",\"municipality\":\"Nantua\",\"county\":\"Ain\",\"state\":\"Auvergne-Rh\xC3\xB4ne-Alpes\",\"country\":\"France\",\"postcode\":\"74910\",\"country_code\":\
"fr\"}}]",
   url=
    #<URI::HTTPS https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&format=json&q=Barrage+de+G%C3%A9nissiat%2C+Rue+Marcel+Paul%2C+Injoux%2C+Franclens%2C+Nantua%2C+Ain%2C+Auvergne-Rh%C3%B4ne-Alpes%2C+Francia+metropolitana%2C+74910%2C+Francia>,
   request=#<struct Faraday::RequestOptions params_encoder=nil, proxy=nil, bind=nil, timeout=nil, open_timeout=nil, write_timeout=nil, boundary=nil, oauth=nil, context=nil>,
   request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.17.3"},
   ssl=
    #<struct Faraday::SSLOptions
     verify=true,
     ca_file=nil,
     ca_path=nil,
     verify_mode=nil,
     cert_store=nil,
     client_cert=nil,
     client_key=nil,
     certificate=nil,
     private_key=nil,
     verify_depth=nil,
     version=nil,
     min_version=nil,
     max_version=nil>,
   parallel_manager=nil,
   params=nil,
   response=#<Faraday::Response:0x0000556afc452060 ...>,
   response_headers=
    {"server"=>"nginx",
     "date"=>"Thu, 15 Oct 2020 19:42:53 GMT",
     "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
     "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked",
     "connection"=>"close",
     "access-control-allow-origin"=>"*",
     "access-control-allow-methods"=>"OPTIONS,GET"},
   status=200,
   reason_phrase="OK">,
 @on_complete_callbacks=[]>
```

Make sure that you use `https` schema, otherwise, you'll get a response with a redirect.

Comment: Do you find something with that address? Cause I have returned an empty json

Comment: query = "Barrage de Génissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Francia metropolitana, 74910, Francia"
    connection = Faraday.new('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org')
    response = connection.get do |request|
      request.params = { format: 'json', addressdetails: 1, q: query }
    end

This code return me nothing but in the website https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org there is a result

Comment: Do you use HTTPS schema?

Comment: Yes, I use your link

Comment: Yes, I got the response. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Could you try to request the same URL by `curl` in the bash console? `curl 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&format=json&q=Barrage+de+G%C3%A9nissiat%2C+Rue+Marcel+Paul%2C+Injoux%2C+Franclens%2C+Nantua%2C+Ain%2C+Auvergne-Rh%C3%B4ne-Alpes%2C+Francia+metropolitana%2C+74910%2C+Francia'`

Comment: Also, I'd check a different URL. For example `http://ip.jsontest.com/`, `response.body` should be `{"ip": "8.8.8.8"}` but instead of `8.8.8.8`, there should be your IP.

Comment: What versions of Ruby and Faraday do you use?

Comment: ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux],
faraday 1.0.1

Comment: For me, it works under the same versions. Please check what the result `curl` will return.

Comment: Empty array even in curl but if i use www.google.it, something it's returned to me

Comment: If `curl` returns the empty result, I can only guess that there are some network or firewall issues. The solution is workable. Try to use another machine. I have no more advice at this point.

Comment: The problem is that if I search only the first part of the address: Barrage de Génissiat I obtain a result....This is really really strange. No, I don't think firewall issue cause the autocompletion is working and it uses same api

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
  query = "Barrage de Génissiat, Rue Marcel Paul, Injoux, Franclens, Nantua, Ain, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes, Francia metropolitana, 74910, Francia"
  connection = Faraday.new('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org')


    response = connection.get do |request|
      request.params = { format: 'json', addressdetails: 1, q: query }
    end


    print Rails.logger.info response.body
```

And I receive `[]`..

Comment: It works perfectly in my Rails console and in a pure IRB session.

Comment: I'm getting crazy. What kind of debug can I do?

Comment: Try to analyze the whole `response` object, `pp response`, `response.status`, `response.env.url`